# What is the analog of '$()' in tcsh?

Tags: tcsh

I tried to do in tcsh the following:

```
$ echo $(pwd)
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command substitution in tcsh is done using backticks: `` `...` ``

```
~> echo `pwd`
/home/muru
```

Comment: Note that it also works in all Bourne-compatible shells, i.e. in bash and dash too.

Comment: Is it correct to say they can't be nested?

Comment: @Mehrdad in (t)csh, [seems so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/whats-the-difference-between-stuff-and-stuff#comment239660_5781).